# SQL LIKE - exact match

Tags: asp.net, sql

Please see the database table below, which I have created to explain my question:

```
CREATE Table Test(id int not null IDENTITY,data varchar(100))
INSERT INTO Test(data) values ('Simon')
INSERT INTO Test(data) values ('David;James;Michael')
```

Please see the SQL statement below:

```
select *
from Test
where data like '%_James%'
    or data like '%James;%'
```

I believe that James will always be found regardless of whether there is one name or multiple names in the table cell, assuming that semi colons are always used as the delimiter.

Another developer said that he would load the values into an array (in ASP.NET or whatever programming language) and loop through the array to find an exact match, however I don't believe this step is necessary as 'James' will always be found.  Is this step necessary?

Comment: Your last insert statement should be: `INSERT INTO Test(data) values ('David;James;Michael')`

Answer (score 2):

It is better to filter in the query. What if there were millions of records? You wouldn't want to retrieve all of this first, just to filter.

Assuming you have to stick with this denormalized schema, I would do it like this. The first two cases can make use of an index on the `data` column. Assumption is that data never has a leading or trailing semicolon:

```
select * 
from Test 
where data = 'James'
    or data like 'James;%'
    or data like '%;James;%' 
    or data like '%;James'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I see what you mean.  Do you see any benefit of loading the values into an array to look for an exact match after running your query?

Comment: No there is no benefit to that.

Comment: The problem is that in this way you will find also names that start or end in `James` - see my answer

Comment: @MiMo no, the semicolons prevent that

Comment: @RedFilter: mhhh..if you have `Jamesson` in the database the first `data like 'James'` will match it - that is probably not what you want.

Comment: @MiMo Not when I try it in SQL Server. But there was a typo I have corrected. `like` should have been `=`.

Comment: No, `like 'James'` is the same thing as `= 'James'`. Omitting the % wildcard operators prevents the partial matches.

Comment: @Giscard Biamby, are you saying that the answer is: select * from Test WHERE data like 'James'  ?

Comment: No, i'm not saying that. I'm saying the first criteria in the WHERE clause of RedFilter's answer could be `data like 'James'` or `data = 'James'`. The two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Using the SQL you pasted, james will be found if there is at least one character before it (e.g., "2James", "BJames", "2Jamesey" would match), or if there is a semicolon after "james" (e.g., "2James;", "BJames;", "James"). But "James" by itself would not match because you used the underscore.

It isn't clear exactly what you are trying to do. Do you only want to find rows where there is an exact match for the word "James" (with "word" boundaries before and after "James", or would you want rows where "James" appears anywhere in the column, even if it's part of a larger word, e.g., "Jamestown"). You could fix by adding `or data = 'James'`. I'm not sure if the underscore thing is doing what you want though, since I'm not sure what your overall goal is. You may or may not need further changes to the query.

Depending on how confident you are that the data in the table is clean, you could write a statement to do what you say. I would keep the search inside the SQL statement rather than pull records out and loop through values in an array, since that could become inefficient in some cases.

Comment: I think that you are missing part of your answer

Comment: I hit save too soon. MiMo's answer addresses the issues I mentioned about what type of data you can expect to encounter within this table. If you have control over how it's structured it is an OK approach. I would favor denormalizing the data though (not putting multiple values in the same field.

Answer (score 1):

No, loading the values in an array is not necessary - and it would be very bad for performance in any case.

Having said that you SQL is a bit strange - if you want to insert the names separated by `;` I think you need:

```
INSERT INTO Test(data) values ('David;James;Michael')
```

Probably it would be even better if you make sure that every name starts and ends with the separator:

```
INSERT INTO Test(data) values (';David;James;Michael;')
```

Then you can use

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE data like '%;James;%'
```

and be sure to always get the correct result.

Last but not least, stuffing multiple valuers in a single column can be done, but it is not the best thing to do in a SQL database, it would be better to keep the names in separate rows in a different table and then have a cross-reference to it (normalizing the structure).

Comment: Thanks.  I see why you have added a semi colon at the beginning - probably will improve performance with only one LIKE statement.  Is there any other point except for performance?

Comment: If you don't add the separators at the start and the end you risk to find partial names - you search for `James` and find also `Jamesson`

Comment: I think RedFilters answer addresses this.  Do you agree?

Comment: No, I don't agree - the only way to avoid incorrect matches is to put the semicolons not only between names but also before and after them - and search for the names with the semi colons before/after.

Comment: I haven't downvoted the answer.  I believe that 'James' would be found in RedFilters answer every time.  If you can think of a scenario that his answer does not cover then let me know before I mark the question answered.

Comment: The RedFilter answer as it is now (with the first `data = 'James'`) works in all cases. Mine works as well - with a simpler query but a messier data (more semicolons).

Comment: @MiMo My query is purposely more complicated so that it will use indexes if possible. Yours is not sargable.

Comment: @RedFilter, because of the `or` conditions, your query will always do a scan on that column (or index if one is available), so one or two of the where conditions being sarge-able doesn't really help.

Comment: @RedFilter Using SQL Server 2008 your query and my query use the indexes in the exact same way - they do an index scan (creating a non-clustered, non-unique index on the column being searched)