# SQL server: using LIKE keyword to find exact match in a CSV field

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and some questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179562/sql-like-exact-match) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805084/mysql-like-operators-find-exact-match). Still I have some issues to get my query to work.

In my table I have a `varchar` field that contains values separated by comma. Examples of real values are:

- T1
- T1, T3, T11, T12
- T26, T1, T11
- T18, T1
- T2, T3

Note: the spaces can be present or not.

My query must find all the records that have, say, `T1` in this field but *not* `T11`. IN the case above all the first 4 rows should be returned.

I know that the pattern for the `LIKE` operator is defined using the placeholder `%`, `_`, `[]` and `[^]`.

But:

- `%T1%` finds also `T11`, `T12`, etc...
- `%T1` works only if `T1` is the last item
- `T1` works only if `T1` is the only item
- `T1%` works only if `T1` is the first item

So I ended up with this query:

```
field LIKE '%T1' OR field LIKE 'T1,%' OR field LIKE '%,T1,%`
```

The first clause finds `T1` if it's the only item or the last item.
The second clause finds `T1` if it's the first item.
The last clause finds `T1` if it's in the middle of other items.

But it does not work if there are spaces (i.e. `T1 , T2`).
I should add all the other cases... It seems a bit ugly to me. Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: 1. Why are you storing delimited data in the first place? That breaks the basic principles of normalisation. 2. If you are using a flawed storage method (delimited) why are leading/trailing spaces being inconsistently applied? 3. Why not normalise your data first, then find the value?

Comment: @Larnu 1. I'm not storing anything... the db is not mine. I'm just reading the values. I cannot edit the database. 2. Because it is the user input... 3. Anyway, I'm looking for normalisation in Google right now...

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Hints: `STRING_SPLIT`, `TRIM`.

Comment: I do not understand your requirement "My query must find all the records that have [...] but not T11", `T11` occurs twice in the first 4 rows.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, yes but I'm not interested in it. I mean if I search for `T1` it should not match also for `T11`

Comment: @Aru Microsoft SQL Server Express 2014

Comment: @jarlh sorry, I was after the `QSqlField` class name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace all the spaces, then add a leading and a trailing delimiter to your column, e.g.

```
 CONCAT(',', REPLACE(field, ' ', ''), ',')
```

converts `T1, T3, T11, T12` into `,T1,T3,T11,T12,`

You can then search for just `,T1,` since you've taken care of the start and end cases by adding the extra delimiters, e.g.

```
 WHERE CONCAT(',', REPLACE(field, ' ', ''), ',') LIKE '%,T1,%';
```

Or, if you are using a version of SQL Server that supports it, you could use:

```
WHERE  EXISTS
       (   SELECT  1
           FROM    STRING_SPLIT(Field, ',') AS ss
           WHERE   TRIM(ss.value) = 'T1'
       );
```

I wouldn't expect this to outperform `LIKE` though

**[Examples on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a1fe6b3d889cf545231dcc7c5144c24d)**

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the spaces and add a comma at the beginning and at the end.

```sql
WHERE
    (',' + REPLACE(field, ' ', '') + ',') LIKE '%,T1,%`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace out space characters to help clean this up:

```
WHERE 
    (
       REPLACE(field, ' ', '') LIKE '%,T1' 
       OR REPLACE(field, ' ', '') LIKE 'T1,%'
       OR REPLACE(field, ' ', '') LIKE '%,T1,%'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work without replace

```
select * from 
(values ('T1'),
('T1, T3, T11, T12'),
('T18, T1'),
('T18, T11'),
('T2, T3'))
as X(field )
where field like '%T1[^0-9]%'
 or field like '%T1'
```